# ADDHTML to add margin not working

Tags: javascript

I am new to the jsPDF.  I am trying to use this code in javascript.  I create the document and i am getting my text correctly in the pdf.  Now i want to have margins.  Here is the code that i have.  But the pdf gets generated with my correct text on the pdf but no margins.  What do i need to do to get margins.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
var f = myWindow.document.createElement("script");
f.type = "text/javascript";

f.text = "function printThis() { var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'in', [11,8.5]);"
 + "var printArea = document.getElementById('PrintableTag');"
 + "pdf.addHTML(printArea, 0, 0, {pagesplit: true, background: '#fff',   margin:{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left:20}},"
 + "function () {pdf.save('Customer.pdf')});"
```

Comment: Your example code is both a) incomplete in that all it does is assign script code to a variable without running it and b) hard to follow since its all inside of a string instead of a code block and c) hard to say whats happening anyway without knowing what `printArea` is since you have not included `PrintableTag`'s markup

Comment: does it work when you try it here: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/